# Change issue status every time when new email was received

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

We are using Redmine for client support system. I had set up receiving emails by Redmine to create new issues. When new email was received, new issues will be created. If email is related to existed issue then the body of the email will put as a comment to this issue.

But, besides this, we need to change issue status from Closed to Feedback every time when new email related to an issue was received.

Do you have any ideas or solution for this problem?

UPD:
We are using Redmine Helpdesk plugin to send emails to supportclients from redmine.

So, when client are answering to this email (that are related to closed task) task need to be reopened automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineReceivingEmails#Issue-attributes) for the allow_override option, in your case, "allow_override=status".

Regards.

Comment: No, it is not solution. Because user need to write status=new in every own letter to support team...